# Continuity of a two variables function - $\epsilon-\delta$ definition

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, metric-spaces

Let's suppose we have a function $$u=u(x,t):[-\pi,\pi]\times(0,+\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$$ such that $u$ is continuous on $[-\pi,\pi]\times[t_0,+\infty)$ for every $t_0>0$.

Can we use the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition (ie, definition of continuity between metric spaces) in order to prove that $u$ is continuous on the whole $[-\pi,\pi]\times(0,+\infty)$?

Any hint would be really appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: As you can take every $t_0>0$, then for given $t_0$ take interval $\left( \frac{t_0}{2}, \frac{3t_0}{2} \right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; let $(x,t) \in [- \pi, \pi] \times (0, \infty)$ and let $\epsilon > 0.$

Since we know $u$ is continous on $[- \pi, \pi] \times [t/2, \infty)$, we can find a $\delta' > 0$ such that $|(x', t') - (x, t)| < \delta'$ and $(x', t') \in [- \pi, \pi] \times [t/2, \infty)$ implies $|u(x', t') - u(x, t)| < \epsilon$.

You can now verify that $\delta:= \text{min}\{\delta', t/2\}$ works on $[- \pi, \pi] \times (0, \infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

No need for $\varepsilon$-$\delta$. For any point $(\theta, r) \in [-\pi, \pi] \times (0, \infty)$, we have $(\theta, r) \in [-\pi, \pi] \times (r/2, \infty)$. From your condition, $u$ is continuous on $[-\pi, \pi] \times (r/2, \infty)$, i.e. $u$ is continuous at every point in $[-\pi, \pi] \times (r/2, \infty)$, including at $(\theta, r)$. Thus $u$ is continuous at every point of $[-\pi, \pi] \times (0, \infty)$.